# custom targets / running arbitrary code

Tags: javascript, makefile, gulp

In `make` it's possible to define custom targets that have no relevance to the actual code that they act upon, in the sense that they are language agnostic.

```make
release_sortof:
         @echo packaging release...
         tar czf release.tar.gz file1 file2 file3
         ls /dev/null
         ls /dev/stderr
         ls /dev/stdout
```

I know the example above is horrible, but the point I'm trying to illustrate is that the code in the `release_sortof` target doesn't depend on the fact that my project uses code written in C, for example; nor does it depend on me using Make built-ins such as `foreach`.

---

Is there a way to work with javascript/`<INSERT-NAME>script` files **without** using the ever insufficient plugins available for gulp?  As in, could I lint my coffeescript with `coffeelint` by directly calling the `coffeelint` module:

```js
var gulp = require('gulp')
  , coffeelint = require('coffeelint')
  ;

gulp.task('lint', function() {
   /* run coffeelint on source files */
});
```

Or can this only be done using plugins?

---

Another example would be to run arbitrary code like so:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
gulp.task('blue', function() {
  var child = spawn('ls');
  /* do stuff with spawned child process */
});
```

Comment: Yes you can.In fact, it's encouraged to *not* use (write) "wrapper plugins": https://github.com/gulpjs/gulp/blob/master/docs/writing-a-plugin/guidelines.md

Answer (score 0):

I do this kind of thing for `browserify` using `vinyl-source-stream` - basically allowing you to use the library as it is, and not using `gulp-*` plugins.

```
var browserify = require('browserify'),
    gulp = require('gulp'),
    source = require('vinyl-source-stream'),
    stringify = require('stringify'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    config = require('../config').scripts;

gulp.task('browserify', function () {
    return browserify(config.app)
        .transform(stringify(['.html']))
        .bundle()
        .pipe(plumber())
        .pipe(source('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(config.dest));
});
```

Heres the npm - https://www.npmjs.com/package/vinyl-source-stream

> Use conventional text streams at the start of your gulp or vinyl
>   pipelines, making for nicer interoperability with the existing npm
>   stream ecosystem.

Maybe that will help you?